# Quantile function returns two numbers, just want one

Tags: r

I can't figure out how to get the number corresponding to a quantile. (Not sure if it matters, but I'm working in RStudio.)

```r
x = rgeom(1e6, 0.01)
q = quantile(x, probs = seq(0, 1, 0.1))
```

`q[3]` returns

```r
20%
22
```

`q[3][1]` returns

```
20%
22
```

and `q[3][2]` returns

```r
<NA>
NA
```

I would like to get the quantity 22. Thanks in advance!

Comment: In your output, `"20%"` is the **name** of the singular value `22`. `length(q[3])` will return `1`. If you do `q[3] + 1`, you will get `20%\n23`. If you really dislike the name being displayed like that (it affects very little), then use `unname(q[3])`.

Comment: I tried q['20%'], with the same result.

Comment: Ah, unname works perfectly. Thanks!